# How to distribute form fields evenly using Bootstrap 4?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I've been trying to to get these fields more evenly distributed, but I haven't been able to do it yet:

**Current**
[image]

**Expectation**
[image]

This is the piece:

```
<div class="row flex-nowrap d-flex align-items-center">
  <div style="width: 37%" class="form-group col-sm col-md-3"><select class="form-control" id="taskList" placeholder="Pick a task">
      <option value=""></option>
      <option value="review and approve on page recommendations">Review and approve</option>
      <option value="review and approve technical seo recommendations">Review</option>
    </select></div>
  <div style="width: 15%" class="form-group col-sm col-md-2"><input type="date" class="form-control" placeholder="MM/dd/yyyy"></div>
  <div style="width: 10%" class="form-group col-sm col-md-2"><input type="link" class="form-control" placeholder="Paste a link"></div>
  <div style="width: 32%" class="form-group col-sm col-md-3"><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Notes"></div>
  <div style="width: 7%" class="form-group col-sm col-md-1"><button id="addTask" type="submit" onclick="addTaskToDb()">+</button></div>
</div>
```

Here is the [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/santosonit/79znvfj8/3/#&togetherjs=ctxw8mv1eg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove `style: width: xx%` from each column, then set class `col-md-x` to each column in order to its sum total 12, so in this case I use 4 + 2 + 2 + 3 + 1, change accordingly to your needs

I used `col-sm` for demo

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.8.3/font/bootstrap-icons.css">
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="row flex-nowrap d-flex align-items-center">
  <div class="form-group col-sm-4">
    <select class="form-control" id="taskList" placeholder="Pick a task">
      <option value=""></option>
      <option value="review and approve on page recommendations">Review and approve</option>
      <option value="review and approve technical seo recommendations">Review</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-sm-2"><input type="date" class="form-control" placeholder="MM/dd/yyyy"></div>
  <div class="form-group col-sm-2"><input type="link" class="form-control" placeholder="Paste a link"></div>
  <div class="form-group col-sm-3"><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Notes"></div>
  <div class="form-group col-sm-1"><button id="addTask" type="submit" onclick="addTaskToDb()">+</button></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Right on point! Thanks a lot! Lots to learn!